# ASP Net Core / Entity Framework form save bug

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a weird bug on my ASP Net Core 2.1 website.

In a specific table, if I save the form, one of the attributes has saved plus ',' chart.
For example, I open the item(open partial view) has value: 'SampleString'
I confirm the form( not edit any attributes), after that the item value is: 'SampleString,'
`Ilo_pass` has the wrong value.

My Controller.cs:

```
umodel.Ilo=         HttpContext.Request.Form["23"].ToString(); 
umodel.Ilo_Pass =   HttpContext.Request.Form["24"].ToString();// this line has the plus ',' chart
  ...
```

The partial view which has the form:

```
                        ...<div class="md-form col-sm-3">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="defaultForm-pass">Ilo User ID</label>
                            <input type="text" name="23"  class="form-control validate" value="@item.Ilo_UserId">
                        </div>
                        <div class="md-form col-sm-3">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" >Ilo Pass</label>
                            <input type="text" name="24" class="form-control validate" value="@item.Ilo_Pass">
                        </div>...
```

And the save method:

```
c.Ilo_Pass = umodel.Ilo_Pass;
...
_application.SaveChanges();
```

The other attributes work well. Any ideas what occurs that problem?

Comment: Do you have another input by that same name on the form?

Comment: omg... I didn't think about that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the answer to **@Crowcoder** . 
The problem was, i have two input field with [24] id.

Comment: So the issue was indeeed caused by the duplicate html input with same name "24", and removing it did resolve the problem.